# Best investment with just 1800 Euros in Estonia

Tags: investing, estonia

I have won a stipend for next 5 mounts of my education in Estonia. I just thought maybe it is better to invest the rest of my money, since I do not need it in the next semester.

The problem is, I do not know what can I do with this little money?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Put it in the bank and earn the meager interest rate.  By far your most important investment is finishing your education and as such this money might be needed to do so.

If you don't need the money during your education you will undoubtedly need it for a new apartment/furnishings/moving expenses.

Comment: +1 - look up the concept of "time horizon" for your money... if you'll need it all to be there in less than 3 years or so, then this is pretty much your only option.  Almost any other option holds the risk of losing you money in that timeframe.

Answer (score 2):

Buy a ticket to a special country/conference/symposium/exchange program, meet people related to your aspirations, get a mentor. I like the previous answer, but in my experience it is much more rewarding to grow career-wise to earn more than it is to save more money.

Answer (score 1):

Estonia is one of the few countries where you can purchase silver tax-free.
You may wish to hedge your risk by investing a percentage of your Estonian currency into this tangible asset. Silver can be stored securely at a place of your choosing rather than in a financial institution. Plus you can purchase a small amount with only minor transaction costs.